# Reverse-Girsanov

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

Let $X_t,Y_t$ be $(\mathbb{P},\mathscr{F}_t)$-semi-maringales.  Under what conditions does there exist a strict-martingale $Z_t>0$ such that
$$
Z_t = X_t + Y_t?
$$

---

**Interest**

In the case where $Z_t$ exist, I guess we can construct a measure change making $X_t$ into $X_t+Y_t$ using Girsanov....